# Eager load a polymorphic association's association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphism, eager-loading

```
class Flat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
end

class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flats, as: :owner
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flats, as: :owner
  has_one :profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

`Flat.includes(:owner)` works fine, but `Flat.includes(owner: :profile)` will fail for agencies. How to include profile only when `flats.owner_type == "User"` in order to prevent N+1 queries?

Comment: Like this `Flat.includes(:profile).where("owner_type" => 'User')` ?

Comment: @Pavan : I still need owner when `owner_type == "Agency"`. This `where` will reject them.

Comment: You want both `User` and `Agency` owner types?

Comment: Yes; and eager load profile when owner is a User.

Comment: I think you have to run a individual query for that too.something like this `Flat.includes(:owner).where("owner_type" => 'Agency')`

Comment: Unfortunately, it costs me more to do 2 `Flat...` + merging results than 1 `Flat...` + N  `Profile.find...`

Comment: Need an expert suggestion here then.Try attracting more users by giving bounty to your post.So that you could get your right answer.

Answer (score 0):

With [squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel) you can do this easily:

```
Flat.joins{owner(User).profile}.includes(owner: :profile).first.owner.profile
Flat.joins{owner(Agency)}.includes(owner).first.owner
```

This query will user 1+n query.